# What are the rules for parameter pack deduction

Tags: c++

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work?

```
template<char... cs> struct StaticString {};

template<char... tail, char... prefix>
constexpr bool startsWith(StaticString<prefix..., tail...>, StaticString<prefix...>)
{
    return true;
}

static_assert(startsWith(StaticString<'a', 'b'>(), StaticString<'a'>()),
              "ab starts with a");
```

Why is tail deduced to be empty?

Answer (score 4):

From [cpprefrence - Parameter pack](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack#Explanation)

> **Explanation**
>   ...
>   In a primary class template, the template parameter pack must be the final parameter in the template parameter list.
>   In a function template, the template parameter pack may appear earlier in the list provided that all following parameters can be deduced from the function arguments, or have default arguments

and [cppreference - Template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Deduction_from_a_type)

> **Deduction from a type**
>   ...
>   If **P** has one of the forms that include a template parameter list **`<T>`** or **`<I>`**, then each element **Pi** of that template argument list is matched against the corresponding template argument **Ai** of its **A**. If the last **Pi** is a pack expansion, then its pattern is compared against each remaining argument in the template argument list of **A**.
>
> *A trailing parameter pack that is not otherwise deduced, is deduced to an empty parameter pack.*

---

To make this work, the compiler must be able to deduce the parameters. This may be done through overloads of `startsWith` with varying template parameters. You can start with the final part, where only the first `StaticString` has any remaining arguments left

```
template<char... tail>
constexpr bool startsWith(StaticString<tail...>, StaticString<>)
{
    return true;
}
```

You then have a failing `startsWith`, where both `StaticString`s differ

```
template<char... tail1, char... tail2>
constexpr bool startsWith(StaticString<tail1...>, StaticString<tail2...>)
{
    return false;
}
```

and finally an overload where the prefix is stripped off and the remaining parts compared

```
template<char prefix, char... tail1, char... tail2>
constexpr bool startsWith(StaticString<prefix, tail1...>, StaticString<prefix, tail2...>)
{
    return startsWith(StaticString<tail1...>(), StaticString<tail2...>());
}
```

Now you can `static_assert` with various arguments, e.g.

```
static_assert(startsWith(StaticString<'a', 'b'>(), StaticString<'a'>()),
              "ab starts with a");
static_assert(startsWith(StaticString<'a', 'b'>(), StaticString<'a', 'b'>()),
              "ab starts with ab");
static_assert(startsWith(StaticString<'a', 'b'>(), StaticString<'a', 'c'>()),
              "ab does not start with ac");
static_assert(startsWith(StaticString<'a', 'b'>(), StaticString<'x', 'a'>()),
              "ab does not start with xa");
```

will result in (Ubuntu 16.04, g++ 5.4)

> a.cpp:23:1: error: static assertion failed: ab does not start with ac
>    static_assert(startsWith(StaticString<'a', 'b'>(), StaticString<'a', 'c'>()), "ab does not start with ac"
>    ^
>   a.cpp:24:1: error: static assertion failed: ab does not start with xa
>    static_assert(startsWith(StaticString<'a', 'b'>(), StaticString<'x', 'a'>()), "ab does not start with xa"
>    ^

Answer (score 3):

Deduction also happens here `StaticString<prefix..., tail...>` and as it is greedy, `prefix` takes all and `tail` is empty.

You then have conflicting deduction for second argument.

Comment: This is not because of "greedy", it's a non-deduced context. 8) The template parameter list that appears within the parameter P, and which includes a pack expansion that is not at the very end of the template parameter list. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction